# Columna Datatable muy ancha

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

Tengo la siguiente DataTable que muestra datos de usuarios, una de sus columnas es la de correos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta sencilla, como puedo colapsar o hacer que el texto se acomodo o se corte (lo que sirva) para que la columna no crezca, ya intente con codigo y nada:

**DATATABLE**

```
function DataTablesLoad() {



            TablaNombreGet = $('#TablaClientes').DataTable({
                 lengthChange: false,
                 autoWidth: true, // must be true for responsive designs when scrolling is enabled
                //, scrollY: 371 // comment out to remove fixed header
                 scrollCollapse: false,
                columnsDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: 0,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return data.substr(0, 10);
                        }
                    },

                ],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    { extend: 'copy', text: 'Copiar' },
                    { extend: 'csv', text: 'CSV' },
                    { extend: 'excel', text: 'Excel' },
                    { extend: 'pdf', text: 'PDF' },
                    { extend: 'print', text: 'Imprimir' },
                    //'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ],
                language: {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
                processing: true

            });

        };
```

**TABLA HTML**

```
<table id="TablaClientes" class="table table-bordered table-hover display nowrap margin-top-10 w-p100 grid" style="width:500px;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID Cliente</th>
                                    <th>Nombre Cliente</th>
                                    <th>Dirección</th>
                                    <th>Telefono</th>
                                    <th>Usuario</th>
                                    <th>Correo</th>
                                    <th>Acciones</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var m in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@m.IdCliente</td>
                                        <td>@m.Nombre_Cliente</td>
                                        <td>@m.Direccion</td>
                                        <td>@m.Telefono</td>
                                        <td>@m.UserName</td>
                                        <td>@m.CorreoCliente</td>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editarUsuario" data-id="@m.IdCliente" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-editarUsuario">Editar</button>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary resetPassword">Reenviar contraseña</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }

                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID Cliente</th>
                                    <th>Nombre Cliente</th>
                                    <th>Dirección</th>
                                    <th>Telefono</th>
                                    <th>Usuario</th>
                                    <th>Correo</th>
                                    <th>Acciones</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Intenta sacarle al `table` la clase `nowrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-overflow` propiedad especifica cómo se debe señalar al usuario el contenido desbordado que no se muestra. Puede recortarse, mostrar puntos suspensivos (...) o mostrar una cadena personalizada.

```
<td><p style="width: 200px; word-wrap: break-word; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">@m.CorreoCliente</p></td>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias